# Can't remove an ampersand from the end of a URL in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I've been breaking my head with a hammer to figure this out but here goes. I'm currently scraping some pages that I get from various source and the URLs often have Google Analytics crap attached to the end of it, in this fashion:

```
&utm_medium=something&utm_source=other
```

And I'm trying to get rid of those from a URL. Since these are appended at the end of a URL, I do this:

```
 $pattern = "^utm_source.*^";
 $interUrl = preg_replace($pattern, '', $url);
```

utm_source is a required portion of the URL for google analytics. Here's my problem shows up. For some reason, I can't get the pattern to match an ampersand like so: "^\&utm_source.*^". Without the ampersand (and its escape), I get matches. So I thought "no biggie, I'll just to a substr" like so:

```
 $finalUrl = substr($interUrl, 0, strlen($interUrl) - 1);
```

But nothing happens. I increased the -1 number to -3 or even -4 but nothing got cut off, not even characters after the ampersand. I've also tried str_replace and even rtrim but none could filter out the ampersand. This is frustrating since I am left with the wrong URL. Not only that, when I try to curl the page, I get a 404 while if I go to that site via my browser, i get redirected to the right page.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

**ANSWER**

While all the answers were nice and technical, I kept trying shit with the regex until I figured something out. The URLs were, for some reason (probably my retrieval method), being encoded so I ended up tweaking the regex like so:

```
$pattern = "/&amp;utm_source.*/";
```

and it works! Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: Are you using `^` as the delimiter, or have you forgotten to use delimiters entirely as well as forgetting that `^` denotes the beginning of a string, and `$` denotes the end? Also, post some real code, I can't make heads or tails of what you're actually trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Agree with @Sammitch, would be good if we had a starting point for the url, and how it should look after your desired transforms

Comment: @Sammitch, yes, I'm using it as a delimiter, I'll change that up real quick. I forgot about the notation but it seems that PHP knows what I'm asking for since it doesn't delete the entire string. I'll update the question with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While all the answers were nice and technical, I kept trying shit with the regex until I figured something out. The URLs were, for some reason (probably my retrieval method), being encoded so I ended up tweaking the regex like so:

```
$pattern = "/&amp;utm_source.*/";
```

And it works.

Why didn't I catch it earlier? I'm running my app on laravel and whenever I use the logging system, it seems to use an actual ampersand instead of & thus it seemed like all was well.

At one point, I went to check the database as to what was happening and noticed that my URLs were ending with & instead of with & (it showed up this way on my view).

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

in your case adding `&` in front of reg expression makes the deal `^&utm_source.*^`

```
<?php 
  $ptn = "^&utm_source.*^";
  $str = "http://someurl.com?index.php&utm_medium=something&utm_source=other";
  $rpltxt = "";
  echo preg_replace($ptn, $rpltxt, $str); // http://someurl.com?index.php&utm_medium=something
?>
```

I am usually using [`explode()`](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/yzf-9b5), to simplify things, but yet again you will need reassemble the url

but you may try [`parse_url()`](https://www.php.net/parse_url) instead of regular expressions, it might be more appropriate in this case.

Comment: i don't see how that helps. I would have to reconstruct the URL afterward and if I ommitted [query], I'd end up without a lot of important information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and [`http_build_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

```
parse_str($url, $vars);

if (isset($vars['utm_source'])) unset($vars['utm_source']);
// unset any other unwanted params the same way...

$finalUrl = http_build_query($vars);
```

Answer (score 0):

By using parse_url like someone else had suggested:

```
<?php
$str = 'http://www.mydomain.com/something.php?herp=derp&some=thing&utm_medium=something&utm_source=other';
$url_arr = parse_url($str);
$query_arr = explode('&', $url_arr['query']);
$final_arr = array();

for($i=0;$i<count($query_arr);$i++) {
        $tmp_arr = explode('=', $query_arr[$i]);
        if(!preg_match('/^utm_/', $tmp_arr[0])) {
                $final_query[] = $query_arr[$i];
        }
}

echo $finished_url = $url_arr['scheme'] . '://' . $url_arr['host'] . $url_arr['path'] . '?' . implode('&', $final_query);

//output: http://www.mydomain.com/something.php?herp=derp&some=thing
```